# Retrieving a file name to attach to an email with SwiftMailer and PHP

Tags: php, html, swiftmailer

I am able to attach a file using SwiftMailer with its name hardcoded.
But what if the file is uploaded by a user from an HTML form's 'file input type control and has to be sent with an email by a PHP script?
How do I specify the file name in SwiftMailer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure in this case you could use the $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] value. This gives the path to the temporary uploaded file.

Comment: Also, if you want to keep the file on your server, just use the move_uploaded_file() function and then pass your destination path to SwiftMailer.

Comment: Somehow it didn't work or perhaps I'm doing something wrong.
Will have to try it again in the morning, with my head fresh.
Thank you!